# Python - Button with imported function

Tags: python, function, button, tkinter, import

I have a problem: the button command is executed when I run the script.

I have been looking for the problem but I haven't been able to figure it out.

I would be so pleased if you can help me.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from config import *
import prueba_browser as pb

#Ejecuta la función del archivo prueba_browser
bok=ttk.Button(miFrame, text="execute", command=pb.openbrowser)
bok.grid(row=2, column=1)
```

This is the file where `openbrowser` function is saved

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import config as c   

def openbrowser():

    browser= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=c.path)
    browser.get("https://www.darkorbit.es")

    login_form = browser.find_element_by_id('bgcdw_login_form_username')
    password_form = browser.find_element_by_id('bgcdw_login_form_password')
    boton_continuar = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//fieldset[@class='bgcdw_login_form_buttons']/input[1]")

    login_form.send_keys(c.usuario)
    password_form.send_keys(c.passwd)
    boton_continuar.click()

openbrowser()
```

Comment: The question is: Why the button command is executed when i run the script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the function in the file that defines it (`openbrowser()` at the bottom).

Remove this call.

Comment: Worked. Thank you very much